# Scripting execute permission along with stored procedure

Tags: sql

In sql is it possible to script permissions as one can with the stored proc itself?  So that I can simply tell somebody to hit execute and the proc and permissions just get created all at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can script the execute permission as follows:

```
use [database_name]
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[stored_procedure_name] TO [user_name]
GO
```

Replace the database_name, stored_procedure_name and user_name values with the appropriate values.

If you include this in your script after the SP CREATE statement it will add the permissions right after the SP is created.

Comment: That does the trick!  (Oddly enough Stack wont let me choose yours as answer for another 8 minutes).